# Global Variable unchanged in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, callback, promise, global-variables

I am working on a JavaScript project. I am using firebase as my backend. I wrote this code and I am having trouble understanding why the

```
alert(name)
```

returns undefined but it shouldn't. The firebase data is not empty. Can someone help me figure it why the global name variable won't change?

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref2 = database.ref('information/');

var id;
var name;

ref2.on("value", function(one) {

    one.forEach(function(two) {

        if (typeof two.val().Id !== 'undefined') {
            id = two.val().Id;

            function program() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    try {
                        var database = firebase.database();
                        var ref = database.ref("users/" + id + "/");

                        ref.on('value', function(user) {
                            resolve(user.val().name);
                        })
                    } catch (e) {
                        reject(e)
                    }
                });
            }

            program().then(function(result) {
                name = result; //I initialize the name variable here and note that if I do alert (result), it does alert a string but it wont change the name variable. 
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            })

        }

        alert(name); //returns undefined. Why?

    });

});
};
```

Comment: if `program().then(function(result) ` does not finish before you alert the name then you will get `undefined`

Comment: you should be alerting the name in the promise's `.then` right under you assign `name = result`

Comment: I know by doing that, it works but in future I am going to have the alert statement replaced with something like string =name + otherVariables + &quot;\n&quot;. And at that time the name will return undefined which I want to avoid. 
Also I am curious why it wont change the name. How should I change my code.